# Why is Angular mat-form-field textarea is blinking while typing?

Tags: html, angular, textarea, mat-form-field

I am using Angular 12 and I have a dialog which contains a form. A the very bottom of the form there is a mat-form-field that contains a textarea. Sometimes (not always) when I open the model and type in the text area the text begins to blink/ flash between the current and previous row. See gif below. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem in stackblitz or anything so I'm not sure what to provide for a mwe.

[image]

Comment: To make a small video, use a video to gif converter tool, like https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif, and enter the gif as an image instead. I usually do and it consumes less space and works on most sites.

Comment: Can you elaborate somewhat on "... the text begins to blink/ flash between the current and previous row" ? Or use a gif. Generally, when using focus or emphasizing functions in JS or JS frameworks, it's important to double check that your groups do not interfere with each others timed visual functions. Not sure which module is handling that here, but make sure classes and groups are not using the same selectors, or this kind of issue would arise.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally someone could drop the code into a online IDE like https://stackblitz.com 
and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: Thank you @andiOak for that converter. I added a gif to my question to show what is happening.

Comment: I wish I could provide a minimal reproducible example but I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. This was given to me by a client and I have absolutely no idea how she got this to happen. Any help would be appreciated if possible. @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero